# Node.js on Windows Azure IIS using IISNode: How to setup node-inspector debugger?

Tags: node.js, azure, iis, iisnode

**ISSUE #1**

When I use `http://127.0.0.1/mysite/node/server.js` URL it shows me my test page, which is OK. But I expect it to show me the node-inspector based debug page when I use `http://127.0.0.1/mysite/node/server.js/debug/` URL. However, this does not work and instead continues to show me the same sample page content.

What should I be doing for the debugger to work?

**ISSUE #2**

Also, I've noticed that when I go to this URL, it automatically gets redirected to

http: //127.0.0.1/mysite/ **public/mysite/** node/server.js/debug/

Why is this happening? Can I avoid this redirection? If yes, how?

**Web.config content**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />


<!-- Web.Debug.config adds attributes to this to enable remote debugging when publishing in Debug configuration. -->
<!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>--> 

<!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Comment out iisnode above, and uncomment iisnode below. -->
<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"
  loggingEnabled="true"
  devErrorsEnabled="true"
  nodeProcessCommandLine="node.exe &#45;&#45;debug"/>

<!-- indicates that the server.js file is a Node.js application 
to be handled by the iisnode module -->
<handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    <add name="iisnode" path="node/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />

    <!-- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment NtvsDebugProxy handler below.
    Additionally copy Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole to 'bin' from the Remote Debug Proxy folder.-->
    <add name="NtvsDebugProxy" path="ntvs-debug-proxy/95a6beca-6da8-493c-b380-2822603aa5dc" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified"
    type="Microsoft.NodejsTools.Debugger.WebSocketProxy, Microsoft.NodejsTools.WebRole"/>
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />

    <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$"/>
    </rule>

    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
    </rule>

    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="node/server.js"/>
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
<!-- <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <clear />
    <!- Remote debugging (Azure Website with git deploy): Uncomment the NtvsDebugProxy rule below. ->
    <!-<rule name="NtvsDebugProxy" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^ntvs-debug-proxy/.*"/>
    </rule>->
    <rule name="app" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="iisnode.+" negate="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite> -->
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: What's your dev environment? Which version of IIS and OS in your side? Do you use Azure Cloud Service for Node.js?

Answer (score 0):

> > ISSUE #1

According to your description, it seems that you debug and test your project on your local host or Azure VM. In this situation, we should **make sure IIS have installed the IISNode module firstly**. So I recommend you can refer to this [document](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)  to make sure you have installed IISNode successfully.
Secondly,**we should check whether project included the your node-inspector configuration**. Also you can use Node.js Sample to check whether your node-inspector is installed successfully.
Thirdly, If you can not use this debugger, **you can press "F12" to trace the debugger error in your Webkit enabled web browser**. If you encountered the error, please share the error on forum and for further support.

> > ISSUE #2

For second issue, it seems that the URL rewrite Rule to lead to this wrong URL.

```
<rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
</rule>
```

For example, if a request was made for this URL: "http://127.0.0.1/content/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=3", so the REQUEST_URI server variable contains content/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=3.

You can get the "http://127.0.0.1/public/content/default.aspx?tabid=2&subtabid=3" as the result. 
I suggest you can refer to this [URL rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule) for more details.